# How to get the Siteurl in prestashop module?

Tags: module, prestashop

I want to get the **SiteUrl** in **prestashop** custom module.How can i achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
if(!empty($member_id)) {
        //set POST variables
        $url = **Here i want my site url**;
        $fields = array(
                    'first_name' => urlencode($FirstName),
                    'last_name' => urlencode($LastName),
                    'username' => urlencode($userName),
                    'email' => urlencode($customerEmail),
                    'membership_id' => urlencode($member_id),
                    'password' => urlencode("admin@12112"),
                    'password2' => urlencode("admin@12112")
                );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`__PS_BASE_URI__` => Website url

Or
`__PS_BASE_DIR__` => website absolut path

Regards,

Comment: With  _ _ PS_BASE_URI _ _ in php OR _PS_BASE_DIR in smarty ?